# C# OpenTK - How do i render Text on screen

Tags: c#, opentk

I have been looking for the answer for this question for a long time, but i have not found any good answers yet. So that is why i decided to go on Stackoverflow to ask you guys.

I only want to render simple text like "Hello World" on to my OpenTK gamewindow,that is all i want. So it there an easy solution for this?

Comment: OpenTK provided a [`TextWriter`](http://www.opentk.com/node/3730).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach (no shaders) is to use System.Drawing to render text into a Bitmap, and then display that Bitmap using OpenGL.

The [TextRendering](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/Source/Examples/OpenGL/1.x/TextRendering.cs) example shows how to do this using OpenGL 1.x.